# PDFLib, Error: Can't import page 1 of PDF document 'document.pdf' (document uses higher PDF version 1.7 than output document)

Tags: php, pdf, pdflib

I'm using PDFLib 9.2.0, and inside my php code, i'm using this method: open_pdi_page

But I encounter this error:

```
Can't import page 1 of PDF document 'document.pdf' (document uses higher PDF version 1.7 than output document)
```

Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You get this error, because you import a newer (higher) PDF version as you create as output. It might be possible, that you set with the `begin_document()` option `compatibility` a PDF version, which is older as the PDF version from the imported document. Please see PDFlib 9.2 Tutorial, chapter 8.3.3 "Document and Page-related Checks" for details.

You can check the PDF version with pCOS (see [starter_pcos sample](https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/pdf_import/starter_pcos/))